# check username already existed with semantic-ui validation and semantic-ui api?

Tags: ajax, validation, semantic-ui

```
$.fn.form.settings.rules["checkUsername"] = function(value) {
var url = "/Index/checkUsername";
var res = true;
$.ajax({
    async : false,
    url : url,
    type : "POST",
    data : {
        username : value
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        if(data['code']==1){
            res = false;
        }else {
            res = true;
        }
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    }
});
};

var validation = {
   username : {
        identifier : 'username',
        rules : [
            { type : 'empty', prompt : 'Please enter your email' },
            { type : 'checkUsername', prompt : 'Username already existed' }
        ]
    }
};
```

It did not work, but the console log is right.

Answer (score 0):

I am using similar kind of validation but not doing an ajax call.

Curious:  Can you put a logging statement just after the ajax call and see if the validation rule is returning before the ajax call?

I would also consider putting the return statement below the ajax call (still inside of the validation function)